# Grid-list view + infinite scroll

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I have simple code in wordpress archive post loop to make a grid view and I want to add 3column-grid / 2column-grid (toggle) switcher

Here is my main code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content-archive" class=".grid col-940">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'loop-header' ); ?>

    <!--// show archive posts in 3 columns -->
    <?php $c=0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $c++;
        if ( $c == 3 ) {
            $style = 'col-300wrap fit';
            $c = 0;
        }
        else $style='col-300wrap';
    ?>

        <?php responsive_entry_before(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($style); ?>>       
            <?php responsive_entry_top(); ?>



            <div class="post-entry">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'archive')); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="trumpai"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __('Pages:', 'responsive'), 'after' => '</div>')); ?>
            </div><!-- end of .post-entry -->
            <?php get_template_part( 'post-meta' ); ?>                
            <?php get_template_part( 'post-data' ); ?>

            <?php responsive_entry_bottom(); ?>      
        </div><!-- end of #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->       
        <?php responsive_entry_after(); ?>

    <?php 
    endwhile; 

    get_template_part( 'loop-nav' ); 

else : 

    get_template_part( 'loop-no-posts' ); 

endif; 
?>  

</div><!-- end of #content-archive -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I need to add this function to show 2 column grid:

```
<!--// show archive posts in 2 columns -->
<?php $c=0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $c++;
    if ( $c == 2 ) {
        $style = 'col-400wrap fit';
        $c = 0;
    }
    else $style='col-400wrap';
?>
```

Beside I need infinite-scroll(plugin) to be active.
How can I combine the code for toggle (aka) grid/list view with infinite scroll and without building two loops (unless toggle button click) to save bandwith?

I found this solution, but I dont know how to combine whole code:

```
/*
 *grid.php: <?php echo "grid loop";?>
 *list.php: <?php echo "list loop";?>
 */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toggle-grid').click(function(){
        // hide both loops
        $(".view").hide();
        // check if loop aleady has been generated
        if ($("#grid").html() != "") {
            $("#grid").show();
        } else { // otherwise fetch loop
            $.get("grid.php", function(data) {
                $("#grid").html(data).show();
            });
        }
    });
$('#toggle-list').click(function(){
        // hide both loops
        $(".view").hide();
        // check if loop aleady has been generated
        if ($("#list").html() != "") {
            $("#list").show();
        } else { // otherwise fetch loop
            $.get("list.php", function(data) {
                $("#list").html(data).show();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

as code author Stefanbar said: the php code would execute on the server side before returning a result back to the js method. The js method will wait until something gets returned.

Any suggestions?

Comment: hi im here to help you so help me help you.(: ok?

Comment: Hi imsiso, thank you for being here (: I could use two different templates and load them separately only on click. I'm new to javascript so I'm asking if it's possible (how) to load 2 column grid template by default and 3 column grid data preload on server side and send data to user only if toggle button is clicked?
 I've tried, but in the result I've got both templates loaded at a time (one hidden with css) therefore infinite scroll was killing my browser. Maybe I'm doing it too difficult, the hint would be great. My code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Andriusas/Bve8S/)

Comment: ok but first let me say you my english is not so good. and do you want this: for example you have 23 posts and you what to show them to user in 2column grid and when user clicks on a toggle button the posts shown in a 3column grid? if this is the thing you want I suggest you to this way.: to load posts an a javascript array() and ceate 2column grid with javascript and array() you have made it. and when user clicks the toggle button user javascript and that array() to make the 3column grid with a javascript code and array(). with this solution you load data from server once and you can do .....

Comment: ...... toggle in different grid type times and times without loading any post data again. just one time load all 23 posts an array and one time the codes for making grids.